# Android keyboard do not show with USB OTG connected

Tags: android

I am getting a strange behavior with edit text and keyboard.
If I have a USB OTG cable connected, the keyboard do not appear when clicked on the edit text. But if I disconnect the cable, the keyboard appears automatically. 
I have tried a lot of functions to force the keyboard shows. 
Whats is the relation of the USB OTG with the keyboard?
I use the USB to communicate with an Arduino.

Regards,

Comment: Presumably, your Android device is thinking that there is a physical keyboard attached. Is the Arduino kit sending some signal down to indicate that it is an HID device?

Comment: It is possible. The Arduino Leonardo is capable to do that. I am using as a serial communication. Is there any way to disable external keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can activate, that the android keyboard should appear even if you have an otg keyboard device connected:

```
Settings -> System -> Languages & input -> Physical keyboard -> "Show virtual keyboard"
```